# What open source solution would work best for auto extracting features from satellite images?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, features, r, feature-extraction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Feature Extraction - Land cover](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9397/feature-extraction-land-cover)

I have been looking for an open source solution which would allow me to define a region (or collection of images) and extract features from such images.

I realize such capabilities are far from perfect however my hope is that there is some type of capability which exists by which I can manually define example features I want to extract and through some type of machine learning procedures they application can identify others which are similar based upon the color variations of the pixels.

My goal is to end up with a vector shapefile which the results of this extraction.

Any assistance or guided procedure would be very helpful here. I would really like to find some solution which works in conjunction with QGIS, GRASS or R.