# Is there an easier way to edit polygons in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, polygon, editing

I am updating woodlot polygons in ArcMap 10. Instead of editing individual verticies, is there a way to edit that is more like drawing part of a new shape (say if the woodlot has expanded only on one side). I'm looking for something similar to the trace tool but I'm working off a tiff image so trace doesn't work. I just want to trace the woodlot and have the existing polygon update to that new shape. Anything to make this task faster would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of moving individual vertices for a feature you can use the [Reshape Feature tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Reshaping_a_polygon/001t00000087000000/) on the Editor toolbar.

Depending on how accurate your polygons need to be you could also leverage remote sensing algorithms to automate polygon creation against aerial imagery that has 4 bands (fourth band that is NIR) or LAS lidar data sets, see:

[Land Cover Feature Extraction from Satellite Imagery](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9397/land-cover-feature-extraction-from-satellite-imagery)

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to use map topolgy on single polygons.
[image: map topology]
Then the reshape, trace, and other tools will work on those objects.

Also the raster snapping on the arcscan toolbar may help you.

[image]