# Where/how can I find/buy/make building footprints for Kent County, MI (Grand Rapids, Wisconsin, etc)?

Tags: data, united-states, footprint

We need building footprints for Kent County, MI along with their associated street addresses.

Primarily we're looking for Grand Rapids and some of Wisconsin, MI, but if someone had access to this data, we'd like Kent County entirely just to be safe.

Do you know anybody/any company that would be able to provide this, or help us find someone that can?

Any ideas?

Comment: contact the geography department at Grand Valley State University.

Comment: I've asked a similar question on this site before focusing on land cover classes, however feature extraction and vectorization of building footprints should be possible, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9397/land-cover-feature-extraction-from-satellite-imagery, you basically nned the aerial imagery and the open source GIS app (see answers within link above).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for currently available data is to use [Kent County Parcel Shapefiles](https://www.accesskent.com/GISLibrary/#Parcels&Streets) which include Michigan Property Tax Codes that seem to correspond with [this document](http://www.michigan.gov/documents/treasury/STC_Recommended_Codes_351268_7.pdf). It seems like Kent County does have information on building footprints judging from [this document](https://www.accesskent.com/Departments/GIS/pdfs/GRDowntown.pdf), but they don't make it readily available. You could try asking for the information from the county.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are short on time, I'll start the ball rolling, though I have no idea if this will work in your case (or if you have already investigated OpenStreetMap):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083291/how-can-i-have-access-to-each-building-in-building-layer-of-google-earth

Comment: but OSM does not have building footprints for Grand Rapids (except for the odd building).

Answer (score 0):

(1) I verified all the known repositories and I could not find lidar for Grand Rapids. Your first task is to also verify with the county, city, state if they have lidar data if they do then your good to go.  I do not want to go into what to do with the lidar yet as you need to find it but check with the city, county, and state.

(2) The only other solution I see if no lidar exists is to throw money at the problem due to the time-frame. Get the latest imagery (preferably orthorectified) from any source then hire a consultant who can operate one of the segmentation softwares such as eCognition to get it processed. I am sure the county will provide the imagery and I found some online from 1998 but more recent likely exists.