# Extracting vegetation polygons from Imagery using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, imagery, digital-image-processing, rgb

I have been trying to roughly polygonize vegetation areas from Imagery (RGB). I tried using [Iso Cluster Unsupervised Classification (Spatial Analyst)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000pn000000.htm) but it is still too detailed for my purpose.

I just need to roughly draw polygons wherever I have dense vegetation as can be seen here:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vegetation extraction is a bit more complex than running the spatial analysis tools that you named.  For better results I would suggest the following:

- run analysis on a 4 band image (e.g. R,G,B,NIR)
- change image to be symbolized as 432 for RGB not 321
- create training samples that represent vegetation and run a supervised classification

These steps will give you a fair result, however you will still get many false returns (e.g. shadows by buildings, or green water bodies...etc).

For best results you will have to use a remote sensing software (including the three bullets above) that analyzes both spectral and textual objects of the imagery.  I asked a question about what free software exists that can do this type of analysis, see link below:

[Land Cover Feature Extraction from Satellite Imagery](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9397/land-cover-feature-extraction-from-satellite-imagery)