# Forming a single TIFF image of a Sentinel 2 tile

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, sentinel-2, gdal-merge

I downloaded the data using the following command from Amazon S3 bucket :

```
aws s3 cp s3://sentinel-s2-l2a/tiles/51/H/VC/2020/10/19/0/ aus1 --recursive --request-payer.
```

Then translated the 13 bands using :

```
gdal_translate ...R10m/B02.jp2 ...B02.tif
gdal_translate ...R10m/B03.jp2 ...B03.tif
gdal_translate ...R10m/B04.jp2 ...B04.tif
gdal_translate ...R10m/B08.jp2 ...B08.tif
gdal_translate ...R20m/B05.jp2 ...B05.tif
gdal_translate ...R20m/B06.jp2 ...B06.tif
gdal_translate ...R20m/B07.jp2 ...B07.tif
gdal_translate ...R20m/B8A.jp2 ...B8A.tif
gdal_translate ...R20m/B11.jp2 ...B11.tif
gdal_translate ...R20m/B12.jp2 ...B12.tif
gdal_translate ...R60m/B01.jp2 ...B01.tif
gdal_translate ...R60m/B09.jp2 ...B09.tif

gdal_merge.py -init 255 -o output.tif B01.tif B02.tif B03.tif B04.tif B05.tif B06.tif B07.tif B08.tif B8A.tif B09.tif B11.tif B12.tif
```

What I want to do after this is supervised classification of these images, classifying them as either land or sea or both.

My question is the TIFF files that I am not sure that the TIFF files I have produced combining all bands is a correct representation for the tile or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine each of the TIFF files into one multiband TIFF file, you should use `gdalbuildvrt`.

The command would be:

```
gdalbuildvrt -separate -resolution highest -r cubic combined-raster.vrt ...B01 ...B02 ...B03 ...B04 ...B05 ...B06 ...B07 ...B08 ...B8A ...B09 ...B10 ...B11 ...B12
```

This would provide a single VRT-raster, which can then either be used directly, or gdal_translate'd into a new TIFF file. It is recommended to convert into a TIFF-file, as you will otherwise have to deal with on-the-fly resampling and other visual issues.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can we convert this .vrt file to tif though?

Comment: Just use 'gdal_translate combined-raster.vrt combined-raster-as-geotiff.tif'

Comment: @NehaJain - perhaps take a look at this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9397/land-cover-feature-extraction-from-satellite-imagery/14996#14996

Comment: Can the jp2 files be used directly in gdalbuiltvrt?

Comment: Yes. jp2 can do directly into gdalbuildvrt, assuming your version has been compiled with that capability (which it generally has been).